# Get the result of FORMSOF

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, full-text-search

I cannot find a way how to execute FORMSOF(FREETEXT,run) and get the result. The thing is I want to get different forms of word and then use those in C# code.

All I can find is how to use it with CONTAINS

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/search/-search-sql-formsof

EDIT:

This select works for me, but I don't want to give the user sysadmin privileges

```
SELECT display_term
FROM SYS.DM_FTS_PARSER('FORMSOF(FREETEXT, run)', 1033, 0, 0)
```

Comment: That has nothing to do with SQL Server; is that where you are trying use it? if so, that's your problem.

Comment: I've edited my post